# sql query not grouping properly

Tags: mysql, group-by

for some reason the query below is allowing duplicate names. Why is that?

```
SELECT id, name_without_variants, SUM(relevance) as total_relevance FROM (
    SELECT 
        card_definitions.id, 
            card_definitions.name_without_variants,
        (MATCH(card_definitions.name_without_variants) AGAINST ('lost soul site discard')) * 0.40 AS relevance
        FROM card_definitions
        GROUP BY name_without_variants, id
    UNION
    SELECT 
        card_definitions.id,
            card_definitions.name_without_variants,
        (MATCH(card_def_identities.special_ability_text) AGAINST ('lost soul site discard')) * 0.05 AS relevance
        FROM card_def_identities 
        INNER JOIN card_definitions ON card_def_identities.card_def_sid = card_definitions.id 
        GROUP BY name_without_variants, id
    UNION
    SELECT 
        card_definitions.id,
            card_definitions.name_without_variants,
        (MATCH(brigades.brigade_color) AGAINST ('lost soul site discard')) * 0.30 AS relevance
        FROM brigades 
        INNER JOIN card_def_brigades ON brigades.id = card_def_brigades.brigade_sid
        INNER JOIN card_definitions ON card_def_brigades.card_def_sid = card_definitions.id 
        GROUP BY name_without_variants, id
    UNION
    SELECT 
        card_definitions.id,
            card_definitions.name_without_variants,
        (MATCH(identifiers.identifier) AGAINST ('lost soul site discard')) * 0.20 AS relevance
        FROM identifiers
        INNER JOIN card_def_identifiers ON identifiers.id = card_def_identifiers.identifier_sid
        INNER JOIN card_definitions on card_def_identifiers.card_def_sid = card_definitions.id 
        GROUP BY name_without_variants, id
    UNION
    SELECT 
        card_definitions.id,
            card_definitions.name_without_variants,
        (MATCH(card_effects.effect) AGAINST ('lost soul site discard')) * 0.05 AS relevance
        FROM card_effects
        INNER JOIN card_def_effects ON card_effects.id = card_def_effects.effect_sid
        INNER JOIN card_definitions on card_def_effects.card_def_sid = card_definitions.id 
        GROUP BY name_without_variants, id
    ) AS combined_search 
GROUP BY name_without_variants, id
HAVING total_relevance > 0
ORDER BY total_relevance DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Here's the result i'm getting. Notice the two `Lost Soul [Site Doubler]`

```
2623    Lost Soul [Deck Discard]    6.35151714086533
1410    Lost Soul [Hand Discard]    6.29273346662521
1495    Lost Soul [Discard Card]    5.93360201716423
1442    Lost Soul [Demon Discard]   5.91308708190918
1497    Lost Soul [Site Doubler]    5.05888686180115
1498    Lost Soul [Site Doubler]    5.05888686180115
2572    Lost Soul [Site Guard]  4.82421946525574
2774    Lost Soul [Far Country] 3.39325473308563
2891    Fortify Site [RoA2] 2.77084048986435
1418    Lost Soul [Hopper]  2.63041100502014
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the IDs are different and you are grouping by ID, you get multiple rows for each, that's what `GROUP BY` does. If you change your top level `SELECT` to

```
SELECT name_without_variants, SUM(relevance) as total_relevance
```

and the outer GROUP BY to:

```
GROUP BY name_without_variants
```

you should see distinct names, but will no longer have the id.

Comment: You will also have to add an aggregate function to the id column if you remove it from the group by statement. You will need min/max or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

```
GROUP BY name_without_variants, id
```

You're grouping by  name_without_variants, id. The id's differ on the two records:

```
1497    Lost Soul [Site Doubler]    5.05888686180115
1498    Lost Soul [Site Doubler]    5.05888686180115
```

You need to decide how you will manage the id.

Remove the id from group by and add an aggregate function to the id columnn in your select. Or just remove the column all together.

Here's an example which has been reduced to single query. Please understand I don't have the full perspective on your schema or data, nor has this been tested. I'm also making some assumptions here. However, if the schema is relational, this should bring back what you're looking for:

```
SELECT cd.id, cd.name_without_variants, (((MATCH(cd.name_without_variants) AGAINST ('lost soul site discard')) * 0.40)+
                                   ((MATCH(cdi.special_ability_text) AGAINST ('lost soul site discard')) * 0.05)+
                                   ((MATCH(b.brigade_color) AGAINST ('lost soul site discard')) * 0.30)+
                                   ((MATCH(i.identifier) AGAINST ('lost soul site discard')) * 0.20)+
                                   ((MATCH(ce.effect) AGAINST ('lost soul site discard')) * 0.05)
                                  ) as total_relevance 
FROM card_definitions cd 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN card_def_identities cdi ON cd.id=cdi.card_def_sid
 LEFT OUTER JOIN brigades b ON cd.id=b.card_def_sid
 LEFT OUTER JOIN identifiers i ON i.id=cdi.identifier_sid
 LEFT OUTER JOIN card_def_effects cde ON cde.card_def_sid=cd.id
 LEFT OUTER JOIN card_effects ce ON ce.id=cde.effect_sid
GROUP BY cd.id, cd.name_without_variants
HAVING total_relevance > 0
ORDER BY total_relevance DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Oh, I thought the group by would group the name, and then if there were still any duplicates, group them by id. I still need the ID though. How can I get just 1 on the ID's, and make sure there are no duplicate names?

Comment: You have to use min/max on the id column. However, then you're going to get an arbitrary id from one of the unioned select statements. It might be wise just to remove the id from the top level select since it won't have much meaning. Otherwise, you will have to add a static column to your union select statements so you know which statement the id came from. Make sense? I can edit the answer to show if needed.

Comment: I need the id. It's the only thing I actually use. If you wouldn't mind, could I see an example? I don't know anything about min/max

Comment: Hmm, which table do you want to use for the authority on id's? Does one of these tables have the id as primary while others have id as foreign?

Comment: card_definitions.id is the important one.  that's what I'll be using

Comment: k, added example to answer. Hope that helps :) Also, if you have problems with the query, break it down to a single join, removing table col references. Then add each join back individually testing between revisions.